# What the crc GET parameter stands for in Adobe Muse world?

Tags: adobe, muse

Most of the assets used by Adobe Muse end with a `crc` GET parameter.

For example:

> site_global.css?crc=496117513

This is valid for all imagery, css and javascript files.

I am wondering why they used it and could it be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably stands for [Cyclic Redundancy Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check), a simple checksum.

It's probably used for cache-busting, to make sure that the URL changes if the content changes.

Comment: That was my guess too, but I did not find a proof anywhere.